# converting public ExampleName ExampleVariable to public GameObject ExampleVariable in C# UnityEngine2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am amking a unity 2D game and i have some variables of a preloaded GameObject that i want to refrence in a script of a prefab but i cant seem to be able to use the GameObject.FindWithTag("VariableName"); (to load the gameobject in the prefab) because the variable is a public ExampleName ExampleVariable instead of public GameObject ExampleVariable, so what im looking for is how to convert the ExampleName to GameObject so i can use .FindWithTag(); func for it,

```
public ExampleName ExampleVariable;
public GameObject ExampleVariable;

void Start()
{
    ExampleVariable = ExampleName.FindWithTag("<GameObjectsName");   // i have this

    ExampleVariable = GameObject.FindWithTag("<GameObjectsName");    // i need this
}
```

i havent really tried much because this is a solution to another problem that i had with refrencing variables in prefabs but i feel like this is the best way to solve the problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: prefabs dont exist they are templates..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, instead of using the .FindWithTag function youe can use the FindObjectOfType function:

**varibale = (Type)FindObjectOfType(typeof(Type));**